# Оптимизация VBA-макроса

Tags: excel, vba

**Суть**: есть 2 листа в книге Excel. На первом листе *номер телефона* и *дата звонка*, на втором листе - *номер телефона*, *дата заявки* и *прочая информация*.

Написал макрос, который для каждого телефона и даты звонка с 1-го листа подтягивает информацию со 2-го листа по условию, что номера должны быть равны, а даты звонка и заявки отличаться не более, чем на 3 дня.

```
For i = 2 To tCnt 'бежим по 1-му листу'
    tNum = Sheets("1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    tDate = Sheets("1").Cells(i, 2).Value
    tCred = 0

    For j = 2 To mCnt 'для каждой строки из 1-го листа пробегаем весь 2-й лист'
        mNum = Sheets("2").Cells(j, 1).Value
        mDate = Sheets("2").Cells(j, 4).Value

        If mNum = tNum And CDate(tDate) - CDate(mDate) <= 3 And CDate(tDate) - CDate(mDate) >= -3 Then
            tCred = tCred + 1
            For k = 1 To 10
                Sheets("1").Cells(i, k + 5) = Sheets("2").Cells(j, k + 1).Value
            Next k
        End If
    Next j

    Sheets("1").Cells(i, 5).Value = tCred
Next i
```

На 1-м листе 30.000 записей, на 2-м листе - 100.000. В результате двойной цикл сделает примерно 3 млрд прогона по строкам, что занимает существенное время. Есть какие-нибудь способы оптимизации, кроме `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`? Например, как-нибудь быстро узнать, есть ли номер с 1-го листа во 2-м листе, и если его нет, то перейти к следующей итерации внешнего цикла, чтобы лишний раз не бежать по 100.000 строкам.

Comment: ну, первое что приходит в голову - это отказаться от Excel и сделать в Access и фигачить нормальными запросами. 2 - выгрузить все значения из 2-го листа в память (хотя бы только списки телефонов) в памяти будет быстрее. 3. Сделать поиск по столбцу (посмотрите `Columns(..).Find(..))`

Comment: Обращение к объектам листа медленное. Записать данные в два массива, обработать и выгрузить на лист готовое. Есть возможность прикрепить файл?

Comment: @vikttur к сожалению, там конфиденциальные данные клиентов. Вы предлагаете загнать все в матрицу вместо листа Excel и обработать так?

Comment: @Sublihim спасибо, попробую 2 и 3 пункт, 1-й не вариант.

Comment: как вариант взять  в память два массива  из регионов на страницах .
В первом 2 столбца и во втором 2 столбца . 

mas1 = sh.Range("A2:B" & nRow).
    For n = 1 To UBound(mas1).
               ваше условие .
если условие сработало - делаем замены на листе.
можно во второи массив больше столбцов взять , прям из массива подтягивать данные для замены на странице.
проверить только совпадение строк (n) массива и страниц ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращение к объектам листа медленное. Записать данные в два массива, обработать и выгрузить на лист готовое.

Код "списан" с кода *Denis*'а, не проверялся (могут быть ошибки).

```
Sub jjj()
    Dim a1(), a2()
    Dim lRws1 As Long, lRws2 As Long, tCred As Long
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    a1 = Sheets("1").UsedRange.Value
    a2 = Sheets("2").UsedRange.Value
    lRws1 = UBound(a1): lRws2 = UBound(a2)

    For i = 1 To lRws1
        For k = 1 To lRws2
            ' для отсечения лишних вычислений условия разделены '
            If a1(i, 1) = a2(k, 1) Then
                If a1(i, 2) - a2(k, 4) <= 3 Then
                    If a1(i, 2) - a2(k, 4) >= -3 Then
                        tCred = tCred + 1
                        ' заполнить лучше без цикла: '
                        a1(i, 6) = a2(k, 2): a1(i, 7) = a2(k, 3)
                        a1(i, 8) = a2(k, 4): a1(i, 9) = a2(k, 5)
                        a1(i, 10) = a2(k, 6): a1(i, 11) = a2(k, 7)
                        a1(i, 12) = a2(k, 8): a1(i, 13) = a2(k, 9)
                        a1(i, 14) = a2(k, 10): a1(i, 15) = a2(k, 11)
                        Exit For ' выходим из цикла k '
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next k

        a1(i, 5).Value = tCred
    Next i

    Sheets("1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(a1), UBound(a1, 2)) = a1
End Sub
```

Comment: Denis, правка некорректна. Объявления переменных (Dim...) обычно пишутся без отступов. В конце комментария апостроф не обязателен

Comment: Про `Dim` не был в курсе, обычно видел, что пишут с табуляцией. Апостроф в конце, чтобы подсветка кода в ответе корректная была. И спасибо за решение, отрабатывает в сотни раз быстрее моего кода :) не знал про этот способ: `a1 = Sheets("1").UsedRange.Value`, пригодится!

Comment: *.UsedRange* - только для примера. Достаточно ограничить диапазон нужными данными

Comment: Просто хочу узнать, что предпочтительнее, работа с массивами в памяти или `Columns(...).Find(...)`?

Comment: Насколько знаю, оператор Find медленный (не проверял, могу ошибаться)... Наверное, зависит от ситуации и на больших массивах обработка в памяти предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 3):

код от друга

по названию саба наидете если что его

```
Sub FromDoober()
Dim a1(), a2()
Dim lRws1 As Long, lRws2 As Long, tCred As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long
a1 = Sheets("1").UsedRange.Value
a2 = Sheets("2").UsedRange.Value
lRws1 = UBound(a1): lRws2 = UBound(a2)
Set C_is1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set C_is2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For i = 1 To lRws1
    C_is1.Item(a1(i, 1) & "") = i

Next
For i = 1 To lRws2
    C_is2.Item(a2(i, 1) & "") = i
Next
Keys = C_is1.Keys
For n = 0 To UBound(Keys)
    If C_is2.Exists(Keys(n)) Then
        i = C_is1.Item(Keys(n))
        k = C_is2.Item(Keys(n))
        If a1(i, 2) - a2(k, 4) <= 3 Then
            If a1(i, 2) - a2(k, 4) >= -3 Then
                tCred = tCred + 1
                ' заполнить лучше без цикла: '
                a1(i, 6) = a2(k, 2): a1(i, 7) = a2(k, 3)
                a1(i, 8) = a2(k, 4): a1(i, 9) = a2(k, 5)
                a1(i, 10) = a2(k, 6): a1(i, 11) = a2(k, 7)
                a1(i, 12) = a2(k, 8): a1(i, 13) = a2(k, 9)
                a1(i, 14) = a2(k, 10): a1(i, 15) = a2(k, 11)
                Exit For    ' выходим из цикла k '
            End If
        End If
        a1(i, 5).Value = tCred
    End If
Next
Sheets("1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(a1), UBound(a1, 2)) = a1 
End Sub
```

сравните время , если у кого будет возможность 
здесь вместо 3 м-рдов всего 30 тыс проходов

Comment: На словарях - однозначно быстрее. Не освоил еще (

Comment: Да я и сам не освоил , если что . Просто знаю что быстрее , и реально быстрее ...

Answer (score 0):

Эта работа для баз данных. Изобретение велосипеда в данном случае чревато потерей времени и сил. Лучше потратьте его на освоение элементарных запросов(SELECT * ...), это гораздо легче VBA. Результат вас приятно удивит. Причем данные хранятся (безопасно!) в базе данных (например Access) а выводите вы их и обрабатываете, печатаете и т.д. в Excel. В VBA подключаете надстройку ADO которая позволит вам читать данные из многих баз. Запросы занимают доли секунд при тысячах и сотнях тысяч записей.