# Проектирование программы онлайн мониторинга

Tags: проектирование, vb.net, visual-basic

По работе необходимо спроектировать и написать систему онлайн мониторинга с коннектом к БД, чтобы с некоторой периодичностью вытаскивать актуальные данные и проверять их на некоторые шаблоны.

Данные примерно будут браться из MySQL БД за последний месяц-два месяца, это порядка 100.000-200.000 записей.

Т.к. я не программист, возникли вопросы в ходе проектирования данной программы:

1. Где лучше лучше хранить данные в программе? Слышал, в Visual Studio можно подключать Data Source, типа сделать свою БД, но насколько это эффективно? Пробовал реализовать всё запросами, но это отрабатывает слишком долго, что не подходит под условия задачи.
2. Т.к. актуальные данные будут сравниваться со всеми данными до этого, то после выгрузки новой порции актуальных данных (предположим, их несколько тысяч выгрузилось) будет идти сравнение со всеми данными, которые уже лежат в программе. Сравнение будет идти по нескольким параметрам. Какие эффективные алгоритмы есть?

Например: выгрузилась новая пачка клиентов из 2000 записей, в программе уже 200.000 лежит. Т.к. новых клиентов надо проверить по схожести с теми, что уже ранее были выгружены, то это 2.000 * 200.000 = 400.000.000 сравнений. И так каждую периодичность при новой выгрузке людей. Как это реализовать оптимальнее и с наименьшей затратой по времени?

P.S. Пишу на vb .net ибо привык к ней и так проще.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понял, есть уже готовая БДшка. Но ты хочешь дополнительно иметь свою в которую будешь подгружать часть данных для обработки. Если я прав, то лучше всего, наверное, будет использовать realm для этих целей...

НО!!!!!!

Но с другой стороны, а почему бы тебе не использовать конкретно ту БДшку напрямую? Для чего вообще копировать данные? Подключайся своей программой к базе данных в интернете и делай что тебе нужно просто правильно формируя запросы.

По поводу дата соурса -- ты просто подключаешь запрос к дата соурсу и правильно обрабатываешь ивенты твоего DataGridView. Основная идея в том, что бы если уж ты хочешь отображать данные -- НЕ ГРУЗИТЬ ИХ ВСЕ. А грузить только видимую часть + некий запас вверх и вниз. Готовые рецепты гуглятся по "c# sql datagridview datasource". Ну или в твоем случае "VB". Если не найдешь - ищи по шарпу, мне точно попадалось на глаза.

По поводу того что будет что-то сравниватся... лично мне неясно понятие "сравниватся".

Тебе все команды сравнения и поиска нужно делать конкретно в запросах SQL. Это будет единственным оптимальным путем отбора/фильтрации/обработки данных. Ибо SQL именно для этого и создавался -- что бы делать это оптимально. То есть дальше уже зависит все от твоих личных умений писать запросы что бы получить нужный результат.

Это ответ в общих чертах что бы ты понимал на что ориентироватся.

Сам я не в "этой теме", но лично я бы делал именно так.

Comment: Есть MySQL БД. Пытался реализовать сравнение с предыдущими данными внутри неё запросами, но работает неприлично долго, хотя я стараюсь писать оптимальные и быстрые запросы. Поэтому хочу грузить на сам комп данные и хранить на нём исходя из предположения, что так сравнение будет происходить гораздо быстрее, если написать эффективный код. Могу ошибаться, т.к. не производил сравнение силами компа)

Comment: предположил, что сравнение будет работать быстрее, т.к. когда то сталкивался с таким уже в этом вопросе - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656721/ и код, приведённый в ответе, отрабатывал довольно быстро. Поэтому встал только главный вопрос - где хранить это всё, чтобы с этим можно было еще быстро работать. Да, я думаю, c# и vb .net почти не отличаются)

Comment: У меня одно обьяснение: **значит были написаны запросы неоптимальные**. Но если ты хочешь работать с локальной БД - твой выбор -- реалм. Это реально лучше чем поднимать на хосте SQL или использовать SQLite. А окроме того -- значительно удобнее и быстрее в освоении.

Comment: Так же нужно иметь ввиду что работая с БД на сервере - ты всегда работаешь с актуальными данными. Копируя данные в другую бд ты всегда будешь работать с НЕ актуальными данными. То есть предпочтительно, все таки, работать через запросы к той бд в даном случае по всем параметрам и пытаться разобратся что в твоих запросах которые ты написал не так и почему конкретно они медленные.

Comment: запросы долгие из-за расшифровки данных в столбцах, чтобы потом по ним сверять значения. И много соединений по текстовым полям. Вариант, конечно, добавить индексы. Да, понимаю, данные будут неактуальны, планирую раз в 10-30 мин добавлять новую стопку клиентов и анализировать их с предыдущими в программе.

Answer (score 1):

Формулировка задачи общая и сложно Вам посоветовать, что-то конкретное.

В целом существует множество типов хранения данных одни хорошо подходят для оптимального поиска. Обычно СУБД поиск по индексам (смотрите как работает поиск по BTREE). Если кратко, то Вы наверное сталкивались с такими индексами в отделе бухгалтерии когда папки расставлены по годам, а внути по отсортированы буквам (это называеться индекс). Таким образом сложность поиск документа за 1998 год сводиться к перебору папок по годам. Дальше натйти пользователя Иванов он живет под буквой "И". Таким образом Вы не перебираете все документы, а знаете куда нужно "идти".

> некоторой периодичностью вытаскивать актуальные данные и проверять их на некоторые шаблоны

Обычно под мониторингом понимают получение

- Качественной характеристика - обычно это проверка высказывания - Работал ли Иванов в 2018 году? (да или нет)
- Количественная характеристика - обычно это значение - Сколько сотрудников работало в 2018 году (1, 3, 15, 245)

С качественными характеристиками вроде все просто. Если подходит под условие, то включаем лампочку (датчики на заводах и т.д.), но я так думаю, что это не Ваш вариант.

Если у Вас количественная харатеристика, то можно порекомендовать Вам использовать колоночную систему хранения ClickHouse, Graphite, InfluxDB. У этих систем есть очень удобные инструменты аналитики (график можно посроить и т.д.)

Если же результат у Вас это видоизмененные данные, то мы говорим не о мониторинге, а о какой-то форме аналитической обработки данных и тут тоже несколько решений:

Если у Вас есть доступ к решению, которое формирует данные, то можно данные требующие обработку отправаить в очередь на "обработку" (обычно этим занимаеться брокер), который положит данные в нужную очередь. Тут можно порекомендовать популярные решения на базе протоколв AMQP, JMS и т.п. В дальнейшем один или несколько процессов будут "разгребать" очередь.

Если все данные для работы есть в базе данных, то в большинстве баз данных существует свой встроенный язык программирования на котором можно написать процедуру обработки ("хранимку" или сделать "проситанную вьюху").

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю системы хранения. Да, у меня количественная характеристика. Сколько клиентов с такими же параметрами (штук 10-15 текстовых параметров) было за 1 неделю, за 1 месяц и за 2 месяца.

Comment: попробуйте текстовые параметры индексировать, например пусть этот параметр цвет рубашки. Тогда пусть существует таблица с цветами рубашки, а в оригинальной таблице вместо текстовых параметров будут просто индексы цвета . очевижно что пройтись по индексу где цвет рубашки 7 гораздо быстрее.

Comment: У меня гораздо сложнее - там много текстовых параметров типа устройств клиентов, где периодически добавляются новые. Но индексы как вариант, спасибо